# Phone Gap - appstore refuses my deployment

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I am new to ios developments, and got stuck when trying to deploy to app store. I just get the same message each time.

What I have made is a very simple javascript applications that is build with phonegap. Phonegap compiles it and I have tried to setup the config.xml file, with the following splash screens.

```
<gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default.png" width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default_at_2x.png" width="640" height="960" />
<gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default_iphone5.png" width="640" height="1136" />
<gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-Landscape.png" width="1024" height="768" />
<gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-Portrait.png" width="768" height="1024" />
<gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-Landscape_at_2x.png" width="2048" height="1496" />
<gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-Portrait_at_2x.png" width="1536" height="2008" />
```

And iconsetup like this

```
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="144" height="144" />
```

The reponse I get from AppStore is as following:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "AutoAkademiet". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
>
> iPhone 5 Optimization Requirement - Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5. New iPhone apps and app updates submitted targeting iOS 6 and above must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5 and must include a launch image with the -568h size modifier immediately following the  portion of the launch image's filename. Launch images must be PNG files and located at the top-level of your bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you localize your launch images. Learn more about iPhone 5 support and app launch images by reviewing the iOS Human Interface Guidelines and iOS App Programming Guide.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, go to the Version Details page and click "Ready to Upload Binary." Continue through the submission process until the app status is "Waiting for Upload." You can then deliver the corrected binary.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

Anyone knows what I have done wrong here? And how may I fix this minor issue with phonegap?

Comment: I think they want your splash/ios/Default_iphone5.png to have -568h like this splash/ios/Default-568h@2x.png

Comment: You can also try to follow this naming convention to prevent further reject base on filename: http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/icons_and_graphics/default-image

Answer (score 1):

The message is quite explicit.

Rename your splash/ios/Default_iphone5.png image to splash/ios/Default-568h@2x.png

Comment: Hi,I Tried that, got the same email back.

Comment: Have you tried to open your generated info.plist file ?
Have you checked your archive and that images are correctly bundled ?

You should have 
splash/ios/Default.png
splash/ios/Default@2x.png
splash/ios/Default-568h@2x.png

Comment: Good idea, I have checked the ipa file by renaming it to zip and checking what images are there. And phonegap adds the pictures, but they are all empty. Dont understand way.

Comment: Images are empty ? Did you mean that they are white, or with a 0 file size ?
If just blank, but non 0 KB, it's normal. When creating archive, PNG are crushed via png crush, and not visible anymore via preview.

Comment: They are in the correct size, but looks like they are completly transparent.

Comment: Just uploaded an app and encountered this problem. I had an incorrect filename that seemed to be holding it up. Got it working with this entry: <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" />

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

It was just an oversight of adding the actual file (.../Default_iphone5.png) to the
git repository which PhoneGap Build pulls from.

Double-check that the file `Default_iphone5.png` is actually
there (in github), including the parent directories splash and ios,
double-check the file size, and that it's a png.

Also, add `gap:platform="ios"` to your XML element.  For example:

```
<gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default_iphone5.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
```